# Can I Programmatically Create FTP Accounts With Azure?

Tags: asp.net, azure, ftp, automation

I'm primarily a PHP developer and am unsure if this is possible on Azure.

So here's the scenario...

When users sign up to my web application I would like to automatically create an FTP space for them on my Azure hosting account using the credentials they supply in a form, I only want them to be able to access their folder on my Azure host.

Is this possible with Azure as I have only just started using it and cant really find an answer for this?

Thanks, Nick

Comment: Are you referring to Azure Blob storage?

Comment: Blob storage doesn't accept FTP protocol though does it?

Comment: As for as I know, Azure Blob does not allow FTP; you need something like [ftp2azure](http://ftp2azure.codeplex.com/). However, you can use Azure VM, and install FTP on it.

Comment: I hope [Deploying a load-balanced, high-available FTP Server with Azure Files](http://fabriccontroller.net/blog/posts/deploying-a-load-balanced-high-available-ftp-server-with-azure-files/) blog post gives you an idea how to setup a FTP service in Azure. On top of that you'll have to build the _automatic FTP space creation_.